# How to access djagno built in login system fields

Tags: django, django-templates, django-login

So when I look on tutorials online on how to use the django built in login system I found that they use `{{ form.as_p }}` in templates, how can I access each field individualy in tmeplates so I can put them in my own styled template ?

Comment: `{{ form.fieldname }}` with `fieldname` the name of the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redefine fields by inheriting default `AuthenticationForm`

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm


class UserLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserLoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    username = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
             'class': 'your-class',
             'placeholder': 'Enter your username',
             'id': 'username-input'
        }))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'class': 'your-class'}))
```

In templates you can access these fileds as `{{ form.username }}` and `{{ form.password }}`

Also you can wrap each field in `<div>` tag and add some classes, for example:

```html
<form action="/your-view/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div id="username-input" class="form-control your-class">
        {{ form.username }}
    </div>
    <div id="password-input" class="another-class">
        {{ form.password }}
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

Comment: so i am overriding the default AuthenticationForm, but where should i put this ? i mean in which file ?

Comment: `your_app/forms.py`

Comment: ok thank you, I don't know much about overriding default objects in djagno but i will look into this, Thank you for replying !

Comment: so is this the only best way for doing this? , so there isn't actual variables to use in django login templates, I mean can't i just use form.username and form.password and applying a class to them in my template ?

Comment: Yes, you can, but you shold wrap each field in `<div></div>`, for example

Comment: I am waiting for the example, Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can lookup login form field names from Django source code. Here -  https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py.